# EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(t.fingerId) - Not working on Android builds - Unity

Tags: unity, c#, android, input, touch

Ok so I have followed through about 5 tutorials and read over 5 separate forum discussions on the above method. For some reason in my game, the touch the UI button does occur, but the touch is also carrying through the button and hitting the ground below. This is in turn triggering my player to move even though i explicitly tell it not to in the same block of code.

It appears to me after much debugging already (I still could easily be wrong obviously else I wouldnt be writing this!), that its all working as it should, and t.phase Began isnt getting called when its on the button. However t.phase Ended is getting called RIGHT AT THE END WHEN I RELEASE THE BUTTON, and all my bools that I added purely to see what was happening change at this time back to currentControlState.MOVE (which is the enum i made for shoot and move. It's supposed to stay as SHOOT until the pointer has completely left the shoot button, but somehow the touch that is registered underneath the button persists long enough to make my code set everything to mvoe to that position.

Basically here is what i wanted to happen: The player will be able to touch any area of the screen , and the 'goodguys' (players characters) will move to that spot using SetDestination in the NavMeshAgent. OK that was all done.
Then if the player touches and holds the Shoot button (the UI button in question regarding this entire post!) , this will turn the enum state to SHOOT. Once in this state, if the player uses a second finger on the world, the 'goodguys' fire in the direction they are currently facing.

All the code was looking fine to me to begin with but it hasnt worked. I posted about trying to find help but didnt get a reply, so thought I'd post a more full version of the question. And this time the complete source code is to follow. Please note I have triple-checked the Inspector in Unity for missing objects, I've checked 'Force Module Active' on the Standalone Input module as suggested, I've added a 'Physics Raycaster' to the main camera as suggested. I've tried dozens of variations/locations of the if statement checking isPointerOveRGameObject...

It must have been 20 straight hours i've been trying to get it to work, and now the code looks worse than ever. Any help would be massively appreciated as always.

Code:

```
public class TouchHandler : MonoBehaviour
```

{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Camera cam;
    GameObject[] goodguys;

```
private void Awake()
{
    goodguys = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Goodguy");
    cam = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount >= 0)
    {
        goodguys = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Goodguy");

        foreach (Touch t in Input.touches)
        {
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(t.fingerId))
            {
                // hit UI , so ignore
                Debug.Log("HIT UI AN IGNORED - YEAH RIGHT!");

            }
            else
            {
                Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(t.position);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                    {

                        Debug.Log("FINGER BEGAN = " + t.fingerId);
                        Debug.Log("BEHIND BUTTON TRUE OR FALSE? = " + EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(t.fingerId));
                        foreach (GameObject goodguy in goodguys)
                        {
                            goodguy.SendMessage("OnTouchStart", hit, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                        }


                    }
                    if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                    {
                        foreach (GameObject goodguy in goodguys)
                        {
                            goodguy.SendMessage("OnTouchMoved", hit, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                        }


                    }
                    if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
                    {

                        foreach (GameObject goodguy in goodguys)
                        {
                            goodguy.SendMessage("OnTouchStill", hit, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                        }


                    }
                    if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                    {

                        Debug.Log("FINGER PRESS ENDED = " + t.fingerId);
                        Debug.Log("BEHIND BUTTON TRUE OR FALSE (ended)? = " + EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(t.fingerId));
                        foreach (GameObject goodguy in goodguys)
                        {
                            goodguy.SendMessage("OnTouchEnded", hit, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                        }


                    }
                    if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
                    {

                        foreach (GameObject goodguy in goodguys)
                        {
                            goodguy.SendMessage("OnTouchCancelled", hit, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// UI button toggles (called via inspector Event Trigger PointerUp and PointerDown methods:
public void UiButtonShootModeToggle()
{
    foreach (GameObject goodguy in goodguys)
    {
        if (goodguy.GetComponent<Goodguy>().currentControlMode != Goodguy.ControlMode.SHOOT)
        {
            goodguy.GetComponent<Goodguy>().currentControlMode = Goodguy.ControlMode.SHOOT;
        }
        else  if (goodguy.GetComponent<Goodguy>().currentControlMode == Goodguy.ControlMode.SHOOT)
        {
            goodguy.GetComponent<Goodguy>().currentControlMode = Goodguy.ControlMode.MOVE;

        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Goodguy : MonoBehaviour {
[HideInInspector] public enum ControlMode { MOVE, SHOOT }
[HideInInspector] public ControlMode currentControlMode = ControlMode.MOVE;
public float bulletSpeed;
public float shotFireDelay;
private float shotFireTimer = 999f;

string firstName;
float health;
NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;
GameObject bulletPrefab;



private void Start()
{
    navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    bulletPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Bullet");
}
private void ShootGun()
{
    shotFireTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (shotFireTimer >= shotFireDelay)
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * bulletSpeed);
        shotFireTimer = 0f;
    }
}

public void SetDestination(Vector3 target)
{
    Debug.Log("at point of settingDestination, currentMode is: " + currentControlMode);

    navMeshAgent.destination = target;



}

// TouchHandler calls these methods and outputs 'hit' to them:
public void OnTouchBegan(RaycastHit hit)
{
    if (currentControlMode == ControlMode.SHOOT)
    {
        transform.LookAt(hit.transform);
        ShootGun();
    }
}
public void OnTouchEnded(RaycastHit hit)
{
    if (currentControlMode == ControlMode.MOVE)
    {
        SetDestination(hit.point);
    }
}
public void OnTouchMoved(RaycastHit hit)
{
    if (currentControlMode == ControlMode.SHOOT)
    {
        transform.LookAt(hit.transform);
        ShootGun();
    }
}
public void OnTouchStill(RaycastHit hit)
{
    if (currentControlMode == ControlMode.SHOOT)
    {
        transform.LookAt(hit.transform);
        ShootGun();
    }
}
public void OnTouchCancelled(RaycastHit hit)
{

}
```

}

Comment: Dammit, exactly the problem I have, did you find a solution?

Comment: @DenisSmirnov sadly no. I have tried multiple solutions from the OnPointer.... methods, but none of them can have the same thumb-press pressing two buttons. The way I am going to try get it working when I get time is to scrap Event Triggers, and make my own check using Raycast from the camera to the UI Screen to see if thumb is over the button